# Flask User Page with ID

Tags: python, flask

I want to have a user page (/users/).
When you open just /users/, you should see your own user profile (if you are logged in, else: Error)
When you giev a get command, like /users/?uid=2999 it should laod the user info of the user with the uid=2999.
The get works, the if you are signed in you see your own profile works too.
But if you are not signed in, there is following error:

```
Bad Request

The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

That's the code snippet:

```
@app.route('/users/')
def users():
    if 'logged_in' in session:
        ret = 0
        user = session['uid']
        c, conn = dbconnect.conn()
        data = c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = (%s)", (user))
        if int(data) == 0:
            flash("Error! Please send a report at martin@tekkkz.com!")
        else:
            data = c.fetchone()
            ret = 1
        c.close()
        conn.close()
        gc.collect()
        if ret:
            return render_template("users.html", nav=2, user=data)
    elif request.args['uid']:
        ret = 0
        user = request.args['uid']
        c, conn = dbconnect.conn()
        data = c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = (%s)", (user))
        if int(data) == 0:
            flash("Invalid User-ID. This user doesn't exist!")
        else:
            data = c.fetchone()
            ret = 1
        c.close()
        conn.close()
        gc.collect()
        if ret:
            return render_template("users.html", nav=2, user=data)
    else:
        flash("You need to be logged in to see your own profile!")
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

Why is there `Bad Reqquest` Error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line, when you are not logged in, and 'uid' is not in the query string.

```
elif request.args['uid']:
```

Flask raises an HTTP error when it fails to find a key in the args.

Instead you should have

```
elif 'uid' in request.args:
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the variables accessing using the URL.
When Flask cannot find the `Key` in the URL it raise **KeyError** 
Variables should be accessed using following syntax

```
any_var = request.args.get('key', '')
```

Where `'key'` is the variable name passed through URL and `''` are the default values.

[Here's link to Flask Request](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#the-request-object)